# Android Market/Google Play URL

Tags: android, google-play

How do I find my application's market URL on the Android Market/Google Play?

Answer (score -14, accepted):

Not sure about the android market, I think they say you can only browse them by phone, but sites like this index them: http://www.appbrain.com/

Comment: This is useful, but doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 47):

The Market URL is formatted like this:

```
market://details?id=com.example.your.package
```

Comment: Yes it works if you open it as intent:
`Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.example.your.package"));
 startActivity(intent);`

Comment: `market://search?q=AppName` also works by opening a search for the text 'AppName'

Answer (score 9):

With the recent market website updates, the following will work both on the device and from non-android web browsers:

```
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.example.your.package
```

However, on the device, this URL will prompt the user whether they want to open the Market app or a Browser.

Answer (score 7):

After the recent brand change, the url now is:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.test